# how to have find on a directory with a changing pattern?

Tags: shell, directory-structure

I have a folder structure like this:

```
/domains/some-domain-1/applications/j2ee-apps
/domains/some-domain-2/applications/j2ee-apps
/domains/some-domain-3/applications/j2ee-apps
```

What is the best way to handle folders like this where the parent and child folders are the same? For example, if I wanted to `cd` to a cousin dir `j2ee-apps` of another domain folder from is there an easy way? What if I wanted to run a `ls` from the top level and get everything in the bottom folders (eg: `j2ee-apps`)?

Does anyone have any clever advice on how best to work with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a variable to hold the variant part. Like so:

```
domain='some-domain-1'
cd /domains/$domain/applications/j2ee-apps
domain='some-domain-2'
cd /domains/$domain/applications/j2ee-apps
```

Since the cd command is the same, you can recall it on your shell with the arrow keys.

Depending on how frequently you do this, you might want to define a function in your `.bashrc`.

```
cdj2(){
  cd /domains/"$1"/applications/j2ee-apps
}
```

Then you can `cdj2 some-domain-1`.

[Shell globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) (aka [pathname expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_06)) can take care of the other part (see [Stéphane Gimenez's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22294/how-to-have-find-on-a-directory-with-a-changing-pattern/22296#22296)). The `find` command would be useful if the directory structures weren't exactly the same, but you still want to see all the files matching a certain name.

`find /domains -name 'j2ee-apps' -exec ls {} \;`

Comment: What is the part on the end: '{} \'?

Comment: I love the function definition suggestion, thanks!

Comment: The funny bit at the end s the way the `-exec` option's arguments need to be formated. `{}` is replaced by the filename(s depending on other args and results). The argument has to be terminated with a `;`, however, the shell interprets the `;` and doesn't pass it to the command unless you escape it with a `\\`.

Comment: I can't seem to get the functions to work though :( Some tutorials say to use 'function name() { ... }' but this differs from your syntax. Neither seems to work. Is there something else special that one needs to do?

Comment: When I put it in my .bash_profile using the 'function name(){...}' syntax it works.

Comment: The `function` part should definitely not matter. The POSIX standard specs function definitions like I've shown, and I've not seen a shell that didn't like it (there are shells that don't like the `function` part).

It may be that you need to close and open your terminal or just run `. ~/.bashrc` (and don't forget the leading period-space).

Answer (score 5):

For `ls`, one can use the following to obtain the full list:

```
ls /domains/*/applications/j2ee-apps
```

To switch from one branch to the other I fear there is no easy way to do what you want.

Comment: Can you do something like this with find?

Comment: *@javamonkey79:*  Yes you can use globs with `find`, eg. `find $HOME/bin/*/c* -name '*a*'` ... `find` also allows regex patterns: see `-regex` in `man find`